# Atom editor - alt + tab?! Is it working?

Tags: atom-editor

I have a problem with the shortcut settings in Atom (Ubuntu 16.04). I'm looking for an option of switching between the tabs using "alt + tab". Somewhere I saw an info that it's already "packed in" but it's not true. So I've been told that I have to change the Keymap. I did it a couple of times using different instructions for example:

'body':
  ctrl-tab ^ctrl': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-tab': 'pane:show-next-item'
  'ctrl-shift-tab ^ctrl': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-shift-tab': 'pane:show-previous-item'

but it failed...I mean - it is working only as long as the tab with the Keymap is open!?! (I've saved it of course before closing!) 
and it is not working when I use the tab option "Split left, right or down" to get double or more views at one time.
Does anyone from You know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Paweł

Comment: The question seems to be not about programming.

Comment: This answer seems to be very helpful!